# What can be done about posters who ask provocative questions and then delete within 2 mins?

Tags: discussion

It's really annoying when posters ask questions and then, almost immediately, delete them.  Contributors who are writing comments/answers or, more likely, checking for dups, are left hanging after wasting their time.  It's particuarly galling for 10K+ contributors, who can see a provocative question, but can no longer reply:(

(starting cooking timer)...

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: If by "provocative", you mean questions that are opinion-laden or trollish, downvote them. If users repeatedly post provocative questions (which are probably going to get downvotes) then delete them (or not), well then they're heading toward a question ban.

Comment: @bluefeet 'coffee' posted one on meta a few mins ago.  It was self-deleted before anyone could get round to posting an answer, (well, dup-close anyway:).

Comment: @MartinJames -  Hey! *shuffles feet* ... not sure my question was a dupe, just too opinionated. Sometime I'll revisit the idea though ;-)

Comment: If it's a good question, flag it for undeletion, if it's a bad question, good riddance.

Comment: Hard to imagine that those comments where not meant to inspire the OP to do what he did.  You want more "consequences"?

Comment: ideally, we should flag and delete quickly...

Comment: It would be nice if , as you are answer a question, you see real-time updates on closure-status. some fancy java stuff

Comment: Post a provocative answer and delete it within 2 minutes?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - I did just that , recently : \  ... maybe Martin was thinking of me

Comment: In my case, I knew that ... at best , it would spur *tons* of content and a few upvotes, but no real physical changes.  Admittedly was a dupe of sorts :it read : "Just thinking aloud, are we too harsh … or is it just the internet?"  ... After I reflected some -  yep, it's the internet , and nothing we can really do

Comment: so... my apologies about that situation OP :`\ . I will be careful next time

Answer (score 1):

There really is nothing much to do in these cases. It's like bad weather, it happens sometimes. Understandable pain, and I know it happened to most of us at least once.

However, I'd personally shy away from answering short and unprepared questions(though if you're looking for points, you must sacrifice that stance a little). Seems like a recipe for that rude response you mentioned(answering a deleted question).